# Communication issue between functions into JS and JSX files

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have made this **function** into a **JS** file...

```
function getColors(isPick, isForecolor)
{
    var chosenFunction = 'getColor(' + isPick + ', ' + isForecolor + ')';
    csInterface.evalScript(chosenFunction, function(result)
    {
        if(result !== 'undefined')
        {
            if (isForecolor == true){
                foregroundHexColor = result;
                // etc...
            }
            else
            {
                backgroundHexColor = result;
                //etc..
            };
        };
    });
};
```

which **get** a **hexadecimal** color **value** from this **function** from a **JSX** file.

```
function getColor(isPick, isForecolor)
{
    var color_PickerCase;
    var decimal_Color;
    var hexadecimal_Color;

    if (isForecolor == true)
    {
        color_PickerCase = app.foregroundColor.rgb.hexValue;
    }
    else
    {
        color_PickerCase = app.backgroundColor.rgb.hexValue;
    };

    if (isPick == true)
    {
        if (app.showColorPicker(isForecolor)){
            decimal_Color = color_PickerCase;
            hexadecimal_Color = decimal_Color.toString(16);
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        };
    }
    else
    {
        decimal_Color = color_PickerCase;
        hexadecimal_Color = decimal_Color.toString(16);
    };

    return hexadecimal_Color;    
};
```

In some way it works, but for some reason I have to do the same thing **two times** so to get the value!!! Any idea why is this happening?

Thank you for your time!!!

**UPDATE**: A correction, it works only at first click. Then needs to clicked two times so to get the value!!!

Comment: _How_ are you using these functions? You mention a click event but don't show that code. That seems to be an important part of the problem.

Comment: @Andy like this `$("#current-color-pick-button").click(function(){getColors(true,true);});`. From JS file of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here is the solution...

```
function getColor(isPick, isForecolor)
{
    var color_PickerCase;
    var decimal_Color;
    var hexadecimal_Color;

    if (isPick === true && app.showColorPicker(isForecolor) === false)
    {
            return;
    }

    if (isForecolor === true)
    {
        color_PickerCase = app.foregroundColor.rgb.hexValue;
    }
    else
    {
        color_PickerCase = app.backgroundColor.rgb.hexValue;
    }

    decimal_Color = color_PickerCase;
    hexadecimal_Color = decimal_Color.toString(16);
    return hexadecimal_Color;    
};
```

As [joojaa](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/18306/joojaa) from [graphicdesign](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/130625/communication-issue-between-functions-into-js-and-jsx-files/130628#130628) said, I was asking for the color before picking it and I was getting the color form the last time!!!